# Analytical solution for optimization problem

Tags: optimization

Suppose we have a vector $p \in \Re ^n$. How can I get analytical solution for that optimization problem: $p = \arg \min {f(x)}_{p \in R} $ if $f(p) = ||p-z||^{2}_{2}  + x||p||_{1} $, where $|| \cdot || $ are $L^1$ and $L^2$ norm and $x > 0$.

**UPD1**
Is it correct if I rewrite $f(p)$ as following:
$f(p) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sqrt{(p-z)^2} + x\sum_{i=1}^{N}|{p}| $ ?

Comment: Have you tried the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ just to get an idea?

Comment: Are you talk about degree?

Comment: your reformulation is correct, but you should not expect an analytical solution for the 1-norm

Comment: Ok. But is there a analytical solution for first fromulation?

Comment: The reformulation is not quite correct, see my answer. the $\sqrt{}$ can be removed and the indices for coefficients are missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sketch for obtaining an analytical solution:

First, we consider only the case $n=1$.
The problem can be written as
$ \min f(p)= (p-z)^2+x |p|$.
Then, by using classical methods and analyzing the cases $p \leq,0$ and $p\geq0$
one can optain that the solution $\bar p$ is given by
$$
\bar p = \tfrac12 \min(z+x,\max(z-x,0)).
$$
I suggest you try to figure out the details by yourself.

For $n>1$, the objective function $f$ can be written as
$$
f(p) = \sum_{i=1}^N \left( (p_i-z_i)^2 + x | p_i| \right).
$$

For this problem the solution can be obtained by minimizing each $p_i$ seperately using the method of the case $n=1$.
This is possible due to the special structure of the problem.
Then the analytical solution can be obtained by putting the individual solutions together in a vector $\bar p\in\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Not clear enough but thank you anyway!